# EditText leftView image fit the size of the EditText Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I want to put an Icon inside an `EditText` so I did like this:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/search_icon"
```

The problem is that the image is bigger than the `EditTex`t so the `EditText` becomes bigger in order to fit the image size. What I want is the opposite: The image should resize in order to fit the `EditText` height, is it possible?

I (desperately) tried with:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

But obviously it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content" ?

Comment: @sasikumar it's already set to wrap_content, I also tried to set a custom height but the image gets cut off

Comment: Hi, do you want an Ilusion approach?

Comment: @Sheychan if it allows me to set an OnClickListener to the leftView sure!

Comment: Ahuh, lemme build something

Comment: edittext.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.arrow_right_normal,0); try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#dd80aa"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="363dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter text here"
        android:marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_contenta"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"/>

</RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this by fixing the height of the edit text.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/beautiful"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>
```

you can use below code for resizing

```
Drawable d = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap();
    byte[] ba;
    do {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        Log.e("BEFORE REDUCING",
                bitmap.getHeight() + " " + bitmap.getWidth() + " "
                        + bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());

        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        Log.e("After REDUCING",
                bitmap.getHeight() + " " + bitmap.getWidth() + " "
                        + bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight());
        ba = bao.toByteArray();
        if ((ba.length / 1024) >= 650) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,
                    (int) (bitmap.getWidth() * 0.95),
                    (int) (bitmap.getHeight() * 0.95), true);

        }

        Log.e("BYTE LENGTH", "" + ba.length / 1024);

    } while ((ba.length / 1024) >= 650);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap in RelativeLayout , on the left set an ImageView with layout_height match_parrent